# Amazon Sagemaker ModelError when serving model

Tags: amazon-s3, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I have uploaded a transformer roberta model in S3 bucket. Am now trying to run inference against the model using Pytorch with SageMaker Python SDK. I specified the model directory `s3://snet101/sent.tar.gz` which is a compressed file of the model (pytorch_model.bin) and all its dependencies.  Here is the code

```
model = PyTorchModel(model_data=model_artifact,
                   name=name_from_base('roberta-model'),
                   role=role, 
                   entry_point='torchserve-predictor2.py',
                   source_dir='source_dir',
                   framework_version='1.4.0',
                   py_version = 'py3',
                   predictor_cls=SentimentAnalysis)
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count = 1, instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge')
test_data = {"text": "How many cows are in the farm ?"}
prediction = predictor.predict(test_data)
```

I get the following error on the predict method of the predictor object:

```
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bc621eb2e056> in <module>
----> 1 prediction = predictor.predict(test_data)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant)
    123 
    124         request_args = self._create_request_args(data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant)
--> 125         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    126         return self._handle_response(response)
    127 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    355                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    356             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 357             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    358 
    359         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    674             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    675             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 676             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    677         else:
    678             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (0) from model with message "Your invocation timed out while waiting for a response from container model. Review the latency metrics for each container in Amazon CloudWatch, resolve the issue, and try again.". See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/roberta-model-2020-12-16-09-42-37-479 in account 165258297056 for more information.
```

I checked the server log error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reasonPhrase contains one of the following prohibited characters: \r\n: Can't load config for '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model'. Make sure that:
'/.sagemaker/mms/models/model' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
or '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it seems like the endpoint is trying to load the pretrained model using the path '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model' and fails.

Maybe this path is not correct or perhaps has no access to the S3 bucket so it cannot store the model into the given path.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29959661)